# Print content of file which is inside a running pod

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes pod named `pod-0` running. Inside, there is `.json` file in path `/var/lib/test`. I want to print the content of this file or get a specific key value of the file and store it in a **golang** variable.

I can't use `kubectl` command anywhere.

Using **golang** **K8sClient**, can you please give me the solution for this problem?

I tried this:

```golang
logs, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods(namespace).GetLogs(podName,&v1.PodLogOptions{}).Context(ctx).Do()
```

But it didn't work.

I want a simple and easily understandable solution.

Comment: (Consider that `pod-1` and `pod-2` will have their own separate copies of this file, and that it's possible for the cluster to delete and recreate `pod-0` outside your control, destroying the file; if you can rearchitect your application to not depend on the temporary pod filesystem it will be more robust.)

Comment: Hello @DavidMaze . Can you please elaborate more. I'm completely new to this technology.

Comment: You will frequently have multiple replicas of a Pod, usually by using a Deployment.  Those replicas do not share files, so you'll have some (possibly variable) number of copies of this file.  But also there are automated tasks that can just delete a Pod; if you have a HorizontalPodAutoscaler that decreases the replica count, or a cluster autoscaler that terminates a node, or if a Pod gets evicted from an over-full node, for example.  I would redesign your application to not need this file copy.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'll give brief what i'm doing. I have 3 maridb statefulset replica running. One of them is master pod and other 2 are slave. these are monitored by maxscale pods. Inside this maxscale pod there is one .json file which contain the info of which out of 3 is mariadb pod is master pod. I'm  trying to retrieve that data. I can fetch this data using Kubectl command, but I'm searching solution where using go K8sclient I can read these file.